# Compile & Fill Jasper Report - XML datasource

Tags: java, pdf, compilation, jasper-reports

I am hoping someone can tell me why the code below is creating an empty pdf file every time?

I am trying to compile, fill and run the `xmldatasource` sample project that ships with JasperReports 4.0.2. Although I am attempting to do it Programatically as I want to use a similar (non ant-based) compilation method in my own software. The same project that comes with Jasper uses ant scripts to create the report and it works. So I know there is no issue with the JRXML files. However, I cannot seem to fill the report with data correctly.

When I debugged the Jasper engine source to see if my XML source document is being loaded correctly I see that the `PARAMETER_XML_DOCUMENT` had the value

> [#document: null]

Do you think this would mean that the XML source file is not being read correctly?

The code compiles and runs without errors and all of the relevant files are generated (.jasper, .jrprint and .pdf) but for some reason the rendered PDF document appears to have only one blank page every time.

Any help is greatly appreciated...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map map = new RenderReportBean().execute("northwind", "OrdersReport");

    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public Map execute(String sourceFileId, String templateId, Integer[] formats) {
        Map params = new HashMap();
        Document document;
        Map<Integer, Boolean> renderedSuccessList = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
        try {

            document = JRXmlUtils.parse(JRLoader.getLocationInputStream(sourceFileId + ".xml"));

            params.put(JRXPathQueryExecuterFactory.PARAMETER_XML_DATA_DOCUMENT, document);
            params.put(JRXPathQueryExecuterFactory.XML_DATE_PATTERN, "yyyy-MM-dd");
            params.put(JRXPathQueryExecuterFactory.XML_NUMBER_PATTERN, "#,##0.##");
            params.put(JRXPathQueryExecuterFactory.XML_LOCALE, Locale.ENGLISH);
            params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, Locale.US);

            JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(templateId + ".jrxml", templateId + ".jasper");

            JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(templateId + ".jasper", params);

            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(templateId + ".jrprint", sourceFileId + ".pdf");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return renderedSuccessList;
        }
        return renderedSuccessList;
    }
```

## OrdersReport.jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<jasperReport
        xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
        name="OrdersReport" pageWidth="500" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="500" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <style name="Sans_Normal" isDefault="true" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
    <style name="Sans_Bold" isDefault="false" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="8" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
    <style name="Sans_Italic" isDefault="false" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="8" isBold="false" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
    <parameter name="CustomerID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString language="xPath"><![CDATA[/Northwind/Orders[CustomerID='$P{CustomerID}']]]></queryString>
    <field name="Id" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[OrderID]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="OrderDate" class="java.util.Date">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[OrderDate]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="ShipCity" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ShipCity]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="Freight" class="java.lang.Float">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Freight]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <variable name="TotalFreight" class="java.lang.Float" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{Freight}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="14">
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="0" y="2" width="356" height="10" forecolor="#ccffff" backcolor="#ccffff" mode="Opaque"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="48" height="10" backcolor="#ccffff" style="Sans_Bold"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="54" y="0" width="87" height="10" backcolor="#ccffff" style="Sans_Bold"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Order Date]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="146" y="0" width="108" height="10" backcolor="#ccffff" style="Sans_Bold"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Ship City]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="259" y="0" width="92" height="10" backcolor="#ccffff" style="Sans_Bold"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Freight]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="14">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="2" width="51" height="10"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{Id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="yyyy, MMM dd">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="54" y="2" width="87" height="10"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.util.Date"><![CDATA[$F{OrderDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="146" y="2" width="108" height="10"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{ShipCity}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="¤ #,##0.00">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="259" y="2" width="92" height="10"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Float"><![CDATA[$F{Freight}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <summary>
        <band height="14">
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="0" y="2" width="356" height="10" forecolor="#33cccc" backcolor="#33cccc" mode="Opaque"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="160" y="0" width="67" height="10" backcolor="#33cccc" style="Sans_Bold"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Total :]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="259" y="0" width="92" height="10" backcolor="#33cccc" style="Sans_Bold"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Float"><![CDATA[$V{TotalFreight}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="227" y="0" width="27" height="10" backcolor="#33cccc" style="Sans_Bold"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

## CustomersReport.jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<jasperReport
        xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
        name="CustomersReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="515" leftMargin="40" rightMargin="40" topMargin="50" bottomMargin="50">
    <style name="Sans_Normal" isDefault="true" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="12" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
    <style name="Sans_Bold" isDefault="false" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="12" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
    <style name="Sans_Italic" isDefault="false" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="12" isBold="false" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
    <queryString language="xPath"><![CDATA[/Northwind/Customers]]></queryString>
    <field name="CustomerID" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[CustomerID]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="CompanyName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[CompanyName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <title>
        <band height="50">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="515" height="1"/>
                <graphicElement/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="515" height="30" style="Sans_Normal"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="22"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Customer Orders Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="21">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="5" width="515" height="15" forecolor="#ffffff" backcolor="#333333" style="Sans_Bold"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Customer Order List]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="50">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="5" y="5" width="100" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" style="Sans_Bold"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{CustomerID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="404" y="5" width="100" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" style="Sans_Bold"/>
                <text><![CDATA[(continued)]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="515" height="1" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <graphicElement/>
            </line>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="5" y="25" width="507" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#ffcc99"/>
                <subreportParameter name="XML_DATA_DOCUMENT">
                    <subreportParameterExpression>$P{XML_DATA_DOCUMENT}</subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="XML_DATE_PATTERN">
                    <subreportParameterExpression>$P{XML_DATE_PATTERN}</subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="XML_NUMBER_PATTERN">
                    <subreportParameterExpression>$P{XML_NUMBER_PATTERN}</subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="XML_LOCALE">
                    <subreportParameterExpression>$P{XML_LOCALE}</subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="XML_TIME_ZONE">
                    <subreportParameterExpression>$P{XML_TIME_ZONE}</subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="CustomerID">
                    <subreportParameterExpression>$F{CustomerID}</subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["OrdersReport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="109" y="5" width="291" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" style="Sans_Bold"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{CompanyName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="40">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="515" height="1"/>
                <graphicElement/>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="20" width="80" height="15"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Page " + String.valueOf($V{PAGE_NUMBER}) + " of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="280" y="20" width="75" height="15"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[" " + String.valueOf($V{PAGE_NUMBER})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Print out the fully qualified paths to the files. Make sure the files can be read by the program. Also, do you have to compile the report each time? Do you have a very simple example that shows the problem? (Something, for example, that others could duplicate without much effort?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I found out the issue and it's a bit of an odd one really as the other means of compiling the templates do not call for the same approach.

The example above uses nested reports and for some reason the runtime compile option requires you to compile both templates individually instead of just compiling the Super report and Jasper picking up the sub-report bu default - as seems to be the case when compiling from ant scripts.

So to make the above code work the line:

```
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(templateId + ".jrxml", templateId + ".jasper");
```

needs to be included for each template (super and sub) that are required for the report.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:
document = JRXmlUtils.parse(JRLoader.getLocationInputStream(sourceFileId + ".xml"));

The API says:
getLocationInputStream

public static java.io.InputStream getLocationInputStream(java.lang.String location)
                                                  throws JRException

```
Tries to open an input stream for a location.

The method tries to interpret the location as a file name, a resource name or an URL. If any of these succeed, an input stream is created and returned.

Parameters:
    location - the location 
Returns:
    an input stream if the location is an existing file name, a resource name on the classpath or an URL or null otherwise. 
Throws:
    JRException
```

If the method is not able to return an input stream, it will return null. Basically the string you are passing as parameter is incorrect. Try passing the absolute path.

Comment: @Dhanagopal_Sivaraman: Thanks for your suggestion but the filepaths are not the issue. As mentioned in my OP there are no compilation errors and all of the necessary files are being output, INCLUDING the rendered report. However, the issue is that the report is blank.